# HOW will mongoose model works

Tags: mongoose

I have a simple express code with mongoose package, I'm facing a problem when trying to save data to mongodb.

model/tank.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
     name: 'string',
      size: 'string' 
    });


    var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', schema,"Tanks");
```

api.js:

```
router.post('/tank',(req,res)=>{

    var tankdata=req.body
    var small=new Tank(tankdata)
    small.save((error,success)=>{
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        else
        {
            res.send(success)
        }
    })
})
```

Here's my error message:

> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose [model()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model) only takes 2 parameters. You should change `var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', schema,"Tanks");` to `var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', schema);`